# Whitelisting browser agents in ModSecurrity

Tags: mod-security

I'm using ModSecurity WAF with Apache. I wanted to know if there's a way I can restrict to only few browser agent type? I want to do this for two reasons:

1. Force the users to use an updated browser.
2. Deny reconnaissance. Thus most bots on the internet use useragent that doesn't reflect a browser or an useragent that uses an outdated browser identifier.

Hence for example, I want to block chrome 69 and below, is there a way that i can use ModSecurity (including the CRS ruleset) to block anything but the following:

```
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

I have removed the OS part to ensure any OS can work.

Comment: I think this is a better suited question for ServerFault. It's a configuration issue, not a security one.

Comment: Please don't unless you have *captive* users - for example in a corporate network. Sending an alert for an old browser can be acceptable, but rejecting unknown ones will give a very bad experience for some users.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you for that. This is for my family so I'm covered. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent` directive in mod_security. You will probably need to use a blacklist approach as described in detail [here](https://flameeyes.blog/2009/02/16/my-idea-works-filtering-by-user-agent-that-is/).